# Why is git marking two separate deleted lines as conflict?

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

I have a file with this content:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

commited on branch `A`.

From this, I create a branch `B` and delete the third line in a commit.
I checkout branch `A` and delete the second line in another commit.

When I merge branch `B` in branch `A`, I get a conflict in that file like this:

```
line 1
<<<<<<< HEAD
line 2
=======
line 3
>>>>>>> B
line 4
```

1) Why is there a conflict if there wasn't the same line modified?
2) Why is it showing like that instead of:

```
line 1
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
>>>>>>> B
line 4
```

that more clearly shows that those lines were deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make sure it doesn't destroy anything, any decent diff program also keeps track of at least two lines of context: one above and one below the added/modified/deleted lines.

When you delete line 3 on branch B, in fact, you modify the block of lines 2-4. Similar, on branch A you modify the block of lines 1-3.

These two blocks overlap and they introduce different changes. Git cannot tell for sure how to merge these changes, that's why it marks them as a conflict.

The content of the file on branch B is:

```
line 1
line 2
line 4
```

but on the current branch (branch A) is:

```
line 1
line 3
line 4
```

Which one is the "correct" version? What do you expect to get after the merge? Git cannot tell. **I** cannot tell. Only you can tell.

#### How to read the conflicting area as reported by Git:

```
line 1
<<<<<<< HEAD
line 2
=======
line 3
>>>>>>> B
line 4
```

In plain English, the block above says: "between `line 1` and `line 4`, there is `line 2` on the current branch but `line 3` on branch B".

The block you suggest:

```
line 1
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
>>>>>>> B
line 4
```

means: on both branches, there is nothing between `line 1` and `line 4`. And this is not true.

You will never encounter such a block in a diff. It basically means there is no conflict between the compared versions of the file.

Comment: +1. Whats interesting about this is: git is not able to merge it automatically but if you open the merge-conflict with kdiff, it is able to merge the files as expected. I thought, kdiff is using the normal `diff`, so why is able to merge it properly? Any thoughts about this?

Comment: Indeed, different diff programs handle the conflicts in different ways. Maybe it ignores the mismatches in the context lines.

Comment: Ah yes, good hint. I may investigate more, what kind of diff-program kdiff is using under-the-hood.

Comment: I recommend setting `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3`. This makes Git store, in the decorated merge-conflict-resolution file, *all three* of the inputs (base, local/left/`--ours`, and remote/other/right/`--theirs`) which makes understanding what both sides did to the base much easier.